# Format Decimal using toString() using latest frameworks. 4.7.2 or core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

There are questions like mine but I feel they are outdated.

```
decimal decimalVar = 18000;
String formated = decimalVar.ToString("{0:N}");
print(formated);
```

I want this result:

```
18000.00
```

but my result is this:

```
{18000:n}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `ToString("F2")`

Comment: Or `print($"{decimalVar:F2}");`, if you want this as part of a larger string.

Comment: It looks like you're conflating `ToString` with string formatting, `myNum.ToString("N")` is roughly equivilent to `string.Format("{0:N}", myNum)`

Comment: In Visual Studio you can put your cursor somewhere in the `ToString` text and press `F1` to open the documentation for [`decimal.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either

```
string formated = decimalVar.ToString("N2");
```

to use `ToString()` or

```
string formated = $"{decimalVar:N}";
```

to use string interpolation.

Both have the same result.

What you were attempting in your question suggests you were perhaps getting the two of these two mixed up.

Comment: Incidentally, it's not so much the framework version as the C# version that's relevant here. String interpolation won't work with an earlier version than C# 6.

Answer (score 1):

just use `ToString("###.00")`like this

```
    decimal num = 18000;
    Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("##.00"));
```

result `18000.00`

assume decimal value like `decimal num = 18000.22m;`
result would be `18000.22`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `decimalVar.ToString("N2")`.

For more information, the documentation is at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Additional examples:

```
double dblValue = -12445.6789;
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays -12,445.68
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N1", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE")));
// Displays -12 445,7

int intValue = 123456789;
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 123,456,789.0
```

**EDIT**: The "N" format adds separators and in your post your "expected result" does not so you may want to use "F" instead. `decimalVar.ToString("F2")`